# Is it OK to use EXIT_SUCCESS / EXIT_FAILURE for error reporting inside a program?

Tags: c, error-handling

Let's say I have a program where I have a global variable much like `errno` (named `project_error`) in which I store the exact errors that happened in the past, but I also want functions to return a simple OK/NOK status to simplify error handling, so that I only check `project_error` if NOK is returned.

Is it OK if I use the standard macros defined in `<stdlib.h>`, or is it better to define my own because those usually mean that you actually exited from the program?

It may be opinion based, but I would like to know if there is any de-facto standard, or common practice.

Errors returned this way may be harmless errors of the type "input is out of bounds" which simply reject the user input and ask again, or fatal errors, which require the caller to cleanup, put a warning, and exit.  That is decided by reading the global variable, not the return value.

Comment: There are no "defacto standards" and for example [everyone](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/err.html) [does](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Checking-for-Errors.html#Checking-for-Errors) [it](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os-example-error-handling/blob/master/main.cpp#L129) [differently](https://github.com/viabtc/viabtc_exchange_server/blob/master/accessws/aw_config.c#L14). As for myself, I usually just `return -__LINE__;`, as usually the errors are not recoverable. But please, save time and don't go with a single global static variable.

Comment: I use the global variable because it's an embedded system, and I can easily show the variable as long LED flashes (1) and short LED flashes (0) which show me easily the error that happened.  I don't do that on desktop programs, where I directly print and exit if necessary

Comment: Voting to close as POB, but the accepted answer is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say EXIT_SUCCESS (0) and EXIT_FAILURE (non-0) are just stdlib defined macros that on POSIX systems are set to these ints for the invoking parent process to just get a vague idea of the program's exit status (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdlib.h.html). I would say that since this is for your own internal use it would just be confusing to the reader if you use these exact values. better define your own names to make your intentions of using these errors only internally clear.

Comment: EXIT_SUCESS and EXIT_FAILURE are from [C11](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22p3) standard, not posix. And, EXIT_SUCESS and EXIT_FAILURE may _not_ be 1 or 0, just integer constants. Och, indeed, on posix,they have to be 0 and 1, from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).

Comment: I think the defines are older than C11, they should be since C89. And I think that by “these ints” he's referring to those integer values given between (), he's not implying (for what I can tell) that those are the integer values the defines have outside POSIX standard.

Comment: @JohnBollinger C11 says they're ICEs.

Comment: Well so it does, @AnttiHaapala.  And upon review, I see that C89 and C99 say the same thing.  The POSIX wording must be warning about non-conforming implementations, then, and if they bothered then I guess implementations may actually have existed that failed to conform in this area.  I have deleted my previous comment.

Comment: @KamilCuk The GNU documentation you cited is wrong. POSIX specifies that [EXIT_FAILURE is non-zero](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdlib.h.html).

Comment: @ShinTakezou thanks for clarifying.  yes i only refer to the POSIX standard requiring the defines to be as i described. maybe my wording wasn't too clear.